# Android - check return to activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have implemented a downloader, when the download is finished, I need to display upload in a list. List in separated activity I return to, when download is finished. Is there any way how to check, from where I have entered the activity? Because I need to update List and I don't know to deremine update. I have tried it in onResume, but this is invokend also after onCreate, so this doesn't solve my problem.

Thanks

**Edit:**

I am calling download this way:

```
                  mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading");
                  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading data...");
                  mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                  mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
                  mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                  DownloadFilesTask downloadFile = new DownloadFilesTask(DownloaderMap.this);
                  downloadFile.execute(myUrl);
                  mProgressDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start your download-Activity using [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), you will be returned to the `onActivityResult()` method, where you will also be able to see if the download (or other action) was a success or not (use [`setResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) for this).

Update:
As you are using an `AsyncTask` you can just put any code you need to be run after completion in its `onPostExecute()`-method. If you need to execute methods local to your `Activity`, it might be easiest to just put the `AsyncTask` as an internal class of the `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Small problem is, that my download activity is Async Task, so I am not calling it with startActivity()...

Comment: @Waypoint: I see. The AsyncTask is not a separate `Activity`, but rather a wrapper for a `Thread`, I will update my answer. Take note that it is important to use the correct terminology for relevant answers ;)

Comment: Thanks for comment, I just don't know, how to make internal class and access it

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to know how to tell, from a particular activity, what called it?

I'm not sure if there are other solutions to this, but the easiest one I can think of would be to put an extra on the intent when you trigger your activity, then read that out in onCreate.

e.g. when constructing your intent  you'd have a line such as

```
newIntent.putExtra("callingActivity", this.getClass().getName());
```

and in the onCreate you'd read that with

```
this.getIntent().getStringExtra("callingActivity");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, problem is then when download activity is finished, I am removing it from stack with finish(), so I am not calling my list activity again, so I cannot putExtra into it I am afraid :-(